# Salesforce - Apex simple Trigger

Tags: before-trigger

I have total 3 quaries on Trigger...

On Delete:

1. Query for related Recipient__c records.  If count > 0, return error (sobject.addError())
   "Please Cancel Request, or Remove Recipients before deleting"
2. Query for related Workflow_Instance__c records where Request_Status__c != 'Cancelled'.  If count > 0, return error:
   "Please Cancel Request before deleting"

On Update:

3. Query for related Workflow_Instance__c records where Request_Status__c != 'Cancelled',  If count > 0, return error:
   "You cannot edit a submitted Request"

I haved tried two ways my level best, please review my code and modify below code.....

**Trigger 1 (Trial):**

```
Trigger PreventDeleteAndEdit on Request__c (before delete, before update){
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            Map<Id,Integer> reqIdWithRepSizeMap=new Map<Id,Integer>();
            for(Request__c req :[Select id,(SELECT id  from Recipients__r where Request__c ) FROM Request__c WHERE Id IN =: Trigger.old)]){
               reqIdWithRepSizeMap.put(req.Id,req.Recipients__r.size());
            }
            for(Request__c reqq :Trigger.old){
              if(reqIdWithRepSizeMap.get(reqq.id) >0){
                reqq.adderror('Please Cancel Request, or Remove Recipients before deleting');
              }
            }
        }if(Trigger.isDelete){
            Map<Id,Integer> reqIdWithWrkinsSizeMap=new Map<Id,Integer>(); 
            for(Request__c reqs :[Select id,(SELECT id  FROM Workflow_Instances__r WHERE  Request_Status__c != 'Cancelled' ) FROM Request__c WHERE Id IN =: Trigger.new)]){
               reqIdWithRepSizeMap.put(reqs.Id,reqs.Workflow_Instances__r.size());
            }
            for(Request__c reqst :trigger.new){
                if(reqIdWithWrkinsSizeMap.get(reqst.Id)>0){
                    reqst.adderror('You cannot edit a submitted Request');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger 2 (Trial):**

```
trigger PreventDeletion1 on Request__c (before delete, before update) {

    if( Trigger.isDelete ) {

        List<Recipient__c> ChList1 = [select id, Request__c from Recipient__c where Request__c IN : trigger.old];
        Map<Id,Recipient__c> requestIdWithRecipient = new Map<Id,Recipient__c>();

        for(Recipient__c reci : ChList1){
            if(!requestIdWithRecipient.containsKey(reci.Request__c)){
                requestIdWithRecipient.put(reci.Request__c,reci);
            }
        }

        List<Workflow_Instance__c> ChList2 = [select id, Request__c from Workflow_Instance__c where Request_Status__c != 'Cancelled' AND Request__c IN : trigger.old];
        Map<Id,Workflow_Instance__c> requestIdWithWorkflow = new Map<Id,Workflow_Instance__c>();

        for(Workflow_Instance__c work : ChList2){
            if(!requestIdWithWorkflow.containsKey(work.Request__c)){
                requestIdWithWorkflow.put(work.Request__c,reci);
            }
        }


        for(Request__c req : trigger.old){
            if(requestIdWithRecipient.containsKey(req.id)){
                req.adderror('Please Cancel Request, or Remove Recipients before deleting');
            }
            else if(requestIdWithWorkflow.containsKey(req.id)){
                req.adderror('Please Cancel Request before deleting');
            }
        }

    }

    else if(trigger.isUpdate ){
        List<Workflow_Instance__c> ChList2 = [select id, Request__c from Workflow_Instance__c where Request_Status__c != 'Cancelled' AND Request__c IN : trigger.new];
        Map<Id,Workflow_Instance__c> requestIdWithWorkflow = new Map<Id,Workflow_Instance__c>();

        for(Workflow_Instance__c work : ChList2){
            if(!requestIdWithWorkflow.containsKey(work.Request__c)){
                requestIdWithWorkflow.put(work.Request__c,reci);
            }
        }

        for(Request__c req : trigger.new){
            if(requestIdWithWorkflow.containsKey(req.id)){
                req.adderror('You cannot edit a submitted Request'');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Hi Manu, I am afraid we will not **modify the below code**. If you are having any specific issue, please post it. Someone will definitely help you.

Comment: @manjit_singh. He's not asking your to write fresh code for him from scratch. He's asking you to point him in the correct direction to tell him what he needs to do to correct his code; something that's fairly simple to do. I think his question is fairly straight forward, he just may not have asked it in a manner that sounded that way to you. Please try to take posts in context and allow for different writing styles. Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing, what is your question?

Comment: kudos to the ones understanding the whole question :)

Comment: @crmprogdev I respect your opinion however the way of asking before the question was edited 7 times implied that he is asking to modify the code below there was no specific problem posted. I will be careful next time.

Comment: @manjit_singh. I understand what you're saying. Its often a matter of interpretation and I do "get" that posts change over time. It's more a case of we all have different writing styles and different abilities when it comes to usage of the english language. It's preferable to ask for clarification than to make assumptions about expectations. It makes for a much nicer and friendly forum. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes, I will definitely work on that. Thank you. I learned something today. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you seem to be having with all of these is that one cannot modify the contents of trigger.old. Instead, you'll need to either create a new instance of the record (or modify trigger.new & you can't modify trigger.new in an after trigger), then do an "update" to those records in order to capture the error message.

You have an additional problem in your Before Delete portion of your code in that you're running both queries for each record. Instead, you want to collect a set of records and run a single query where possible on all the Ids all at once rather than 2 queries every time you go through the loop. Your code isn't "bulkified" or "bulk safe" as we'd say because you have your SOQL queries inside of a for loop.

```
 if( Trigger.isDelete ) {
 list<Request__c>errlst = new list<Request__c>();
 for (Request__c Pa : Trigger.Old)
 {

    // Here you're querying for a list with every record that's passed from Trigger.Old each time it goes through the loop.
    list<Recipient__c> ChList1 = [select id, Request__c from Recipient__c where Request__c =: pa.id];

    if(ChList1.size() > 0){
       // can't add pa.adderror method to trigger.old
       errlst.add(pa);
       errlst..adderror('Please Cancel Request, or Remove Recipients before deleting');
    }
}

if(errlst.isEmpty() == False) delete errlst;
    // this will cause your error messages to appear
```

I'm confident you can figure out how to collect the records and combine them on your own into a single set or some method where only the ones that need to be queried are first being added to a set, then queried.

Test to see if you can combine the queries too; something you may or may not be able to do, but at least test to determine whether or not you need to run the query based on whether or not you have records in the set you've collected.

```
elseif ( Trigger.isUpdate )       

for (Request__c Pa : Trigger.Old)
{

// this loop should be run on trigger.new
```

Again, you need to add your records to a new list and also add an update statement following the end of the for loop.

Note: the above was written before @Eric edited your post to make Trigger 2 visible. didn't see it until I was finished.